# Backspace a plus sign (+) from a UITextField - weird bug

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, ios-4.2

I googled this and found nothing - has anybody noticed!

• Find a UITextField on an iOS 4.2 device - anywhere seems to work.
• Type something then enter a plus sign (+).
• Press backspace.

The plus sign AND the next letter are deleted, as if you'd press delete twice!  Also if you enter a string of plus signs, backspace will take out the lot (plus the next character!).

I was about to spend hours finding the bug in my code - but its wider than that!! :-)

I tested it in the simulator - same result, but only for 4.2, older versions don't do this!

I've not installed 4.3, has it gone, does it need reporting - or worse, is it somehow by design?!

Ben.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I haven't yet filed a bug, but I should.

Answer (score 4):

I see it on my ipod (4.2) but can't get it on my ipad (4.3) so maybe they fixed it.

You can always file a bug if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any logical reason for this to happen, so I don't think it's by design. I think you need to report it.

If it has been fixed in 4.3 they'll tell you.

http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that it is an add symbol and that it adds to the amount of text deleted is a very big coincidence. It must be experimental code gone wrong. You also can't move the cursor to the middle of a piece of text like this: x+. I'm using iPod touch iOS 4.